# Wrap node template

Tags: theming, nodes

Using the blog module, I'm setting a custom template for the individual blog articles (`node--blog.tpl.php`) which contains a list item and the content inside.

However, I can't figure out where I should be putting my wrapping `<ul>` tag? If I put it in either `page.tpl.php` or `region--content.tpl.php` then the entire page content is (understandably) wrapped including pagination and other elements. I just need to wrap the list items.

Thanks and please be gentle with a newb :)

EDIT: code

**page.tpl.php**

```
...
<?php print render($page['content']); ?>
...
```

**region--content.tpl.php**

```
<?php if ($content): ?>
 <div class="<?php print $classes; ?>">
  <ul class="blog-list">
   <?php print $content; ?>
  </ul>
 </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**node--blog.tpl.php**

```
...
<li>
 #content#
</li>
....
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about  code you wrote, for which you want to write better code, or you want to understand why it doesn't work, but you didn't show the code you are using, or the part of the code that is relevant for the question. See [Help Center](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Mołot Apologies, I've now added my code. It's core Drupal stuff (using Zen theme). I need to work out where to put `<ul class="blog-list">` so it correctly wraps _only_ the list items (being populated by `node--blog.tpl.php`. Thanks

Comment: it should be `node` not the page or region

Comment: @Drupalist I'm using a custom node template (`node--blog.tpl.php`) for each list item but I need to wrap _all_ list items in a `<ul>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a guess that you're talking about the /blog page, the content is built in [`blog_page_last()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21blog%21blog.pages.inc/function/blog_page_last/7). The nodes themselves will be in `$build['nodes']` when that function returns.

As with pretty much everything in Drupal there are a bunch of different ways to alter that content; I think the easiest in this case would be to use [`hook_page_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_page_alter/7):

```
function MYMODULE_page_alter(&$page) {
  if (current_path() == 'blog') {
    $page['content']['system_main']['nodes']['#prefix'] = '<ul>';
    $page['content']['system_main']['nodes']['#suffix'] = '</ul>';
  }
}
```

Comment: Added to template.php and that worked - thanks Clive! Thanks for the link to the docs - I'll have a read through to try and better understand. This seems insanely difficult for the sake of two HTML tags.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal, where a complicated website will take you about an hour to build, and changing a few HTML tags will take about a day and a half ;) If I could suggest some more reading, [Render Arrays](https://drupal.org/node/930760) will help to understand what's going on with the `$build` that gets returned from the blog function, and what the `#prefix` and `#suffix` stuff really means